# What Is The Purpose of Node.Exe's Program Window

Tags: node.js, windows, command-line-interface

If on Windows one clicks on the shortcut for NodeJs one is presented with a command line interface. Yet none of the commands which run in the NodeJs shortcut command window nor PowerShell window seem to work within the NodeJs command window.

The program itself `node.exe` is one which can be published and used as such, but what is this command line and where is the documentation on it?

[image]

Comment: It's the REPL

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_repl_terminal.htm

Comment: That's the Node REPL

Comment: @WiktorZychla your response is not a comment but an answer. Create an answer as such and I will mark it as such. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This commandline app is the node's REPL:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_repl_terminal.htm